# NSFetchedResultsController: How to get sectionName from to-many relationship of the entity

Tags: ios, core-data, nssortdescriptor, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a core data model as such:
`ParentObject <--->> ChildObject`

Both `ParentObject` and `ChildObject` have an attribute `levelNumber` as:

```
typedef enum {
    Primary,
    Secondary,
    Tertiary
} LevelNumber;
```

I also have a method to convert the level number from int to string in both ParentObject and childObject:

```
-(void) levelString
{
    switch(self.levelNumber)
   {
      case Primary: return @"Primary";
      case Secondary: return @"Secondary";
      case Tertiary: return @"Tertiary";
      default: return @"Error";

   }

}
```

Now I have a FetchedResultsController in a tableview which lists the `ParentObject`.
What I am trying to get in the section name is:

- **If the `ParentObject` is `Secondary` or `Tertiary`, show the section
  name as `Secondary` or `Tertiary`.**
- **If the `ParentObject` is `Primary` but any of the `ChildObjects` are `Secondary` or `Tertiary`, show the section name as `Secondary` or `Tertiary`.**
- **If the `ParentObject` and all the `ChildObjects` are `Primary`, show section name as `Primary`**

Its quite straightforward if I only had to look into the `levelNumber` of the `ParentObject`, something like the following-

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"ParentObject"];
NSSortDescriptor *levelNumSD = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"levelNumber" ascending:YES];
request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:levelNumSD, nil];

self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                    managedObjectContext:myContext
                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:@"levelString"
                                                                               cacheName:nil];
```

I understand that the restriction in FRC is that the result of the SortDescriptor should return the results in the same order as would be liked to display.
How can I incorporate the `ChildObject` checks here as well. Would it be a new kind of SortDescriptor, or something else?

Comment: IMO Have a separate attribute `sectionLevelNumber` in your Parent Object Model.

Comment: https://devforums.apple.com/message/682121#682121 this might help you.

Comment: @Bala If I understand correctly, the attribute `sectionLevelNumber` will not itself store any value but its getter will actually look into the `levelNumber` of `ParentObject` as well as all `ChildObjects` and see which level number to return. This will be a problem because in the first fetch of the FRC, it expects the values to be stored in the database, rather than derived during runtime.

Comment: Mundi has explained it clearly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at Apple's sample code [DateSectionTitles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html) which explains how to have dates as sections and which you an use pretty much for your case as well. The actual display of the string you manage in `titleForSection` but you keep an attribute in the database that is "primitive" and sortable, called `sectionIdentifier`.

In your particular case the section identifier would be just like `levelNumber` and be calculated simply by returning the highest `levelNumber` of all children.

The pattern is as follows:

```
-(NSString*)sectionIdentifier {
   [self willAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];
   NSNumber *tmp = [self primitiveSectionIdentifier];
   [self didAccessValueForKey:@"sectionIdentifier"];

   if (!tmp) {
      NSNumber *childrenMax = [self valueForKeyPath:@"@max.children.levelNumber"];
      tmp = childrenMax.intValue > self.levelNumber.intValue ?
            childrenMax : self.levelNumber;
      [self setPrimitiveSectionIdentifier:tmp];
   }

   return tmp;
}
```

And don't forget to reset it if the entities change.

```
-(void)setLevelNumber:(NSNumber)newNumber {
   [self willChangeValueForKey:@"levelNumber"];
   [self setPrimitiveLevelNumber:newNumber];
   [self willChangeValueForKey:@"levelNumber"];

   [self setPrimitiveSectionIdentifier:nil];
}
```

Finally, make sure it becomes invalid when relevant data changes:

```
+(NSSet*) keyPathsForValuesAffectingSectionIdentifier {
   return [NSSet setWithObject:@"levelNumber"];
}
```

To monitor changes in `levelNumber` of any children have the parent listen for `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` and look to see if any of its children are in that save.

Comment: Good answer! I have some questions though: 1) If "levelNumber" is registered in `keyPathsForValuesAffectingSectionIdentifier`, is it still necessary to override `setLevelNumber`? 2) Is the `@` in "@children" a typo or on purpose? 3) Would changing the levelNumber of a ChildObject really invalidate the sectionIdentifier of the related ParentObject? Perhaps overriding `setLevelNumber` in the ChildObject would be useful. Thanks!

Comment: 1) Yes, this is good practice and does no harm. 2) Typo. Corrected it. 3) You are right in principle, but I would worry about the interdependency of the entities. Ideally you encapsulate this functionality into the parent entity only.

Comment: But with your present code, modifying the levelNumber of a ChildObject would not update the sectionIdentifier of the related ParentObject. Because "children" in keyPathsForValuesAffectingSectionIdentifier does only affect the addition/removal of a child object to the "children" relationship, but not modifying an already related child object (unless I am mistaken).

Comment: That's right. You will have to go to the children entity after all. Best to override `setLevelNumber`.

Comment: This doesn't work completely. What should be used for `request.sortDescriptors`?. If I use just the `levelNumber` of `parentObject`. It gives the error: `CoreData: error: (NSFetchedResultsController) The fetched object at index 2 has an out of order section name '2(Secondary) Objects must be sorted by section name'`. This happens when, for example, all the `ParentObject` are `Primary`, but one of the `ChildObject` of second `ParentObject` is `Secondary`. I can't use the `sectionIdentifier` to sort since it is a transient property.

Comment: Solved the issue by having another intermediate attribute in `parentObject` which gets updated when the `levelNumber` of either the `parentObject` or `childrenObject` updates, and then combining it with the answer given here to get the desired result.